# Including links within Rmarkdown tables (pdf)

Tags: r, pdf, pdf-generation, r-markdown

I am trying to include links to particular webpages in a 'kable' table in Rmarkdown, when creating a pdf.

The table has 4 columns, and I wish for the links to be in the second column, which currently includes strings. The output of the table is given below;

```
    knitr::kable(ind_rank_table_final,row.names = FALSE,caption = "Industry Rank",align = rep("l",ncol(ind_rank_table)))
```

Comment: That's absolutely doable, but what's the question/problem? Please include a reproducible example, eg I have no idea what is `ind_rank_table_final`, so it's hard to try to help.

Answer (score 11):

Using `paste0`, you can construct markdown-formatted URLs in your dataframe, and then pass that to `kable`, like so:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---
```{r}
# some urls
urls <- rep("https://stackoverflow.com/", 10)
# use paste0 to compose markdown-formatted hyperlinks
mtcars$mpg <- paste0("[", mtcars$mpg, "](", urls, ")")
# print the table, with hyperlinked text
knitr::kable(head(mtcars))
```
````

And you can see the result, blue text in the mpg column, and if I hover my mouse over, I see the URL:

[image]

If you want to print the URLs in the table, and have them clickable, then you'de do something like this `mtcars$mpg <- paste0("[", urls, "](", urls, ")")` like so:

[image]

Is that what you're after? This use of `paste0` is pretty handy for doing all sorts of things to tables, for example, [combining multiple values in one cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781769/rmarkdown-table-with-cells-that-have-two-values), and [applying conditional formatting (like bold for significant values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690118/bold-formatting-for-significant-values-in-a-rmarkdown-table)

Comment: You can also use `pandoc.link` from the `pander` package (or `pandoc.link.return` to capture the results instead of sending to `stdout`) if you do not want to construct the markdown URL manually.

Comment: Is there a specific version of kable for this to work? I have tried and generates tex errors. I have the same use case kable + pdf_book output

Comment: In bookdown the links would print as `[21](https://stackoverflow.com/)` aso. and not as clickable links for me. Would you have any suggestions @Ben? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For those knitting to PDFs using bookdown, @Ben's answer will not get you fully the way there. As @mavericks pointed out, you will still see the full text (`[21](https://stackoverflow.com/)`, to keep with @maverick's example).

To fix this, add the argument `format = "pipe"` or `format = "simple"` to `kable()`. The "latex" option, while generating a working link, will display like @maverick's example. The default behavior for `kable()` is to automatically determine the format, which I guess in the case of a bookdown document must be "latex"?

I don't know, but this should generate @Ben's first table for bookdown users:

---

### output: bookdown::pdf_document2

```
# some urls
urls <- rep("https://stackoverflow.com/", 10)
# use paste0 to compose markdown-formatted hyperlinks
mtcars$mpg <- paste0("[", mtcars$mpg, "](", urls, ")")
# print the table, with hyperlinked text
knitr::kable(head(mtcars), format = "simple")
```