# Insert Hyperlink datatable column R

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, desctools

I want to link HTML in R, I have this main datatable,

```
id     mean 
22     12
17     23
```

and I have HTML file with datatable with name are report_22 (report_id) and this table I have just information for id 22

When I click on id 22 in the firt datatable, I want to open report_22 for example.

I want to to this for all my user.

report are in directory :

```
C:\Users\windows\Documents\dossier1
```

In case when we don't have html for an ID I want to put an other link 
as google for example

```
library(DescTools) ## to use the function like

### vector with all file with report in name
link <- as.data.frame(list.files('C:/Users/windows/Documents/Doc Bonus_malus',pattern = "^report"))
names(link) <- c('test')
link$test <- as.character(link$test)
path <- getwd()
path <- rep(path,nrow(link))
path <- paste(path,link$test,sep='/')
```

[Including links within Rmarkdown tables (pdf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35078430/including-links-within-rmarkdown-tables-pdf) (I want to adapt this code in my case)