# Selecting and colouring single table cells with kableExtra in R markdown cell_spec

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I use R markdown in combination with LaTeX to create dynamic PDF reports. To generate the summarizing tables I use the **kableExtra** package.

I'd like to change the styling of individual cells.

Example: Consider the R dataframe `mtcars[1:10, 1:5]`. Using this would be rendered into some nice table:

```
kable(mtcars[1:10, 1:5], format="latex", booktabs = T)`
```

[image: Rendered table]

Now I want to change the style of certain cells. Say the 2nd and 8th entry of *mpg* should be green, the 4th and 5th of *disp* should be orange and italicized and the last four entries of *drat* should be red and bold. And the same cells should be like that, no matter which entries are in the cells.

I'm perfectly aware of the documentation and the examples, such as row and column specific colouring. But the documentation for *cell_spec* deals only with conditional logic depending on the cell values, while I'd like to colour the cells independently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you have seen, the `cell_spec` function is useful if you want to colour a whole row or column. As `kableExtra` does not supply a function to directly edit a single cell, the "easiest" way to do this is to directly paste the LaTeX commands into the cell. I have used this approach in a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49656650/7347699):

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
---

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}

df <- mtcars[1:10, 1:5]

df[1,5] <- paste0("\\underline{", df[1,5], "}")
df[1,1] <- paste0("\\textcolor{red}{", df[1,1], "}")
df[2,2] <- paste0("\\textcolor{green}{\\textbf{", df[2,2], "}}")
# # Equivalent to:
# library(kableExtra)
# df[1, 5] <- cell_spec(df[1, 5], "latex", underline = T)
# df[1, 1] <- cell_spec(df[1, 1], "latex", color = "red")
# df[2, 2] <- cell_spec(df[2, 2], "latex", color = "green", bold = T)

knitr::kable(df, format="latex", booktabs = T, escape = F)

```
````

[image]

You can adapt this to work for your example. You may want to check out the available LaTeX formatting here: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bold,_italics_and_underlining

Comment: I added some `cell_spec` examples for people who don't want to remember too much latex ;)

Comment: @Hao I prefer that method :) hadn't realised you can do it like that

Comment: Hao, thank you for adding the latex equivalent. I needed a bit more flexibility (a cell *partially* bolded) - hopefully, that will do the trick!

Comment: how to achieve this in html output?

Comment: Short of time to answer, but recommend looking at the docs: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html